# Find a book named Solution manual: Steps in commutative algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to have a book name Solution manual: Steps in commutative algebra R.Y Sharp

I don't have so much experimence about commutative algebra.

So someone here have a file or link about this Solution manual book

Please help me